# Nginx on ec2 instance does not serve static files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-linux-2

## What was working

I have MERN stack dashboard up and running on AWS EC2 instance.

- Ec2 instance is at **ec2...aws.com**
- React app is served on port **5004**.
- Node app is running on port **5003**.

## What was changed

The problem started when I set up the domain at GoDaddy to forward (with masking)
from **somebusiness.com** to **ec2.....aws.com**.

First, I set up **NGINX** reverse proxy to serve **/** as my react app (frontend) and **/api** as my node app (backend)
*(you will find nginx code down below later)*

**http://somebusiness.com/** <- opens up React app and is **working correctly**
**http://somebusiness.com/api/heartbeat** <- not working as I expected (heartbeat is just endpoint to check if the app is alive) but for some reason, does not return application/JSON but rather a text/HTML webpage with the correct 'real URL' inside a frame of some kind:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Somebusiness Dashboard</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://ec2-...aws.com/api/heartbeat" frameborder="0" />
</frameset>

</html>
```

The actual URL in the frame is the one that is working as expected:
**http://ec2-...aws.com/api/heartbeat** <- is **working correctly**

I think **GoDaddy** has something to do with this because on GoDaddy I can specify title, description, and keywords for this forwarding. So as backend, I'm forced to use http://ec2-...aws.com/api/ as my backend URL, which is OK for now (it is my **secondary problem** at the moment since it's just convenient to use the domain name for backend as well)

## Main Problem

if i send a request to
http://ec2.....aws.com:5003/uploads/avatars/user1.jpg
the image **is loaded OK**.

So if i send a request to
http://ec2.....aws.com/api/uploads/avatars/user1.jpg
the image **is NOT loaded**.

So to recap: **http://ec2-...aws.com/api/** is working OK for routes and requests, but not for serving **static files**. That leads me to believe my nginx setup is wrong, and I've spent countless hours trying all kinds of different setups. Here I present where i left it:

## Source & code for help

Since I'm using **Amazon Linux 2,** I've used its tools to install **nginx1** and set-up reverse proxy.
When i used NGINX on my other VPS, there was a bit different structure to it (sites-enabled & sites-available folders). But on this nginx there is only **nginx.conf** file where I did the setup. (I guess it doesn't make difference, just wanted to note that)

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  eyeratereviews.com;
        root         /home/ec2-user/somebusiness-web-backend;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5004;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api {
            root /home/ec2-user/somebusiness-web-backend/uploads/avatars;
            default_type application/json;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5003;
            # Following is necessary for Websocket support
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

My node.js project folder structure is like this
...
controllers/
models/
static/
 - pictures/
-- logo.png
uploads/
- avatars/
-- user1.jpg
-- user2.jpg
-- ...

Comment: As you have already accepted an answer for the original question, I would suggest that you revert this edit and create a new question which focusses on the additional problem.

Comment: @RichardSmith okay, will do shortly.

Comment: @RichardSmith please take a look at my additional problem with this kind of setup in my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59320668/blocked-a-frame-with-origin-ec2-url-from-accessing-a-frame-with-origin-domain-ur) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing code does not attempt to remove the `/api` from the front of the URI before passing it upstream. Add a trailing `/` to both the `location` and `proxy_pass` values. For example:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5003/;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

---

Alternatively, use a `rewrite...break` to modify the URI instead.

For example:

```
location /api {
    rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5003;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Awesome, this did the job! It also solved the problem that i had to rewrite my backend to use /api/ before the already existing routes.