# How to rewrite url in nginx after matching the location

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am learning nginx, trying to setup an in-house server. My configuration is:

```
upstream app{
    server app:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location /api/app/ {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I want to request nginx with **localhost/api/app/admin**, but my app can only respond to **app:8000/admin**. Hence, I want only **admin/** to be passed to the application. I tried using rewrite, but was not able to get the desired result.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309405/nginx-on-ec2-instance-does-not-serve-static-files/59312241#59312241).

Comment: That did not work. That answer is probably not relevant to this issue. Doing that is equivalent to requesting my nginx with localhost/admin

Comment: I want to request my nginx with localhost/api/app/admin, but my app can only response to app:8000/admin